# How can I populate my JTable with my embedded database?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, derby, embedded-database

I am having trouble showing my database filled JTable within my GUI application.

My code below runs through and creates a GUI with a panel, I then create my JTable and add it onto my application. I then run through a method that supposedly populates the table. After the populating has finished, nothing shows.

Dissecting my code, I'm led to believe somewhere is causing the data not to parse into my table, for some unknown reason, which is why I have come here.

At the click of a button, this code entails:

```
JTable tigerTable = new JTable();

JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();

centerPanel.add(tigerTable, new GridBagConstraints());

FillTable(tigerTable, "SELECT * FROM TIGER_INFO");
```

The FillTable method as follows:

```
//Add buildTableModel method
public void FillTable(JTable table, String Query)
{
    try
    {

        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:STOCK_CONTROL");
        Statement stat = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(Query);
        System.out.println("Connected");

        //Remove previously added rows
        while (table.getRowCount() > 0)
        {
            ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).removeRow(0);
        }

        int columns = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();

        while (rs.next())
        {
            Object[] row = new Object[columns];

            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
            {
                row[i - 1] = rs.getObject(i);
            }
            ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).insertRow(rs.getRow() - 1, row);
        }

        rs.close();
        stat.close();
        conn.close();         
    }
    catch (InstantiationException |
            IllegalAccessException |
            ClassNotFoundException |
            SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Doing so creates the application, but does not show any table with data. My database contains 3 columns and 3 rows, but I do not see my data displayed inside a JTable.

My question is, how can I populate my JTable with my database and display it correctly on my GUI application?

If you need anything else, please let me know and I will provide as much as I can.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution - I've been trying  to wrap my head  around the problem for way too long, and I finally fixed it.

Try setting the table model manually first.

```
JTable tigerTable = new JTable();
tigerTable.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(0, numberOfColumns));
```

When you don't specify a model, the JTable creates an anonymous inner class and generally doesn't behave how you want it to.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mix the operation, i suggest to use this instruction :

1. Create a Bean, or Entity to store the information of your Object
2. Get the List of your data,
3. Display your data in your JTable,

So you can use this to display your data in your JTable :

```
....
List<TIGER_INFO> list = new ArrayList<>();//create a List of data
while (rs.next()){
   //fill data in your List
   list.add(new TIGER_INFO(rs.getTYPExxx("att1"), rs.getTYPExxx("att2"), rs.getTYPExxx("att3"));        
}

//when you finish call your function which display your data :
fillData(list);
....
```

Fill date method can look like this :

```
private void fillData(List<TIGER_INFO> list) {
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTableName.getModel();

    while (model.getRowCount() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
            model.removeRow(i);
        }
    }

    for (TIGER_INFO obj : list) {
        model.addRow(new Object[]{
            obj.getAttribute1(),
            obj.getAttribute2,
            obj.getAttribute3
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I create a variable for my database table? `String myTable = "TIGER_INFO"`?

TIGER_INFO has a red line under it.

Thank you.

Comment: You mean you want to replace the name of your table in this query `FillTable(tigerTable, "SELECT * FROM TIGER_INFO");` if that yes you can create this variable and concatenate it with this name `FillTable(tigerTable, "SELECT * FROM " + myTable  );` if not explain more @juiceb0xk

Comment: `List<TIGER_INFO> list = new ArrayList<>();` - At the moment, TIGER_INFO is underlined with red. I'm assuming we're making an array list from my table; how do I make the TIGER_INFO variable to point towards my TIGER_INFO table?

Comment: aaaahhh, i told you, you have to create a Class similar of your table, which contain your fields you can learn more here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm if you don't get it i will make an example ok @juiceb0xk good luck

Comment: Thank you very much. i will try as best I can to get this running.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137668/discussion-between-juiceb0xk-and-ycf-l).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to write a class extending AbstractTableModel. Add a function to this class filling the content based on a SQL-Statement.  Then it will look something like:

```
TigerTableModel tigerModel = new TigerTableModel(dbConnection);
tigerModel.executeQuery("select * FROM TIGER_INFO");
JTable tigerTable = new JTable(tigerModel);
```

or you create a generic TableModel that is able to run every SQL-statement, so you are very flexible in your project.